# Issue in implementing JS Pulltorefresh into Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement the pull to refresh module into my AngularJS application using resource from here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/127/how-to-implement-a-pull-to-update-effect-android-refresh-style-with-javascript

As of now I pasted the code into my controller say X.

```
PullToRefresh.init({
        mainElement: ('#page-refresher'),
        onRefresh: function(){
            $scope.tasks();
        },
        distThreshold : 50, // Minimum distance required to trigger the refresh.
        iconArrow: '<span class="la la-arrow-down"></span>', // The icon for both instructionsPullToRefresh and instructionsReleaseToRefresh
        instructionsPullToRefresh: "Pull Down to Refresh",
        instructionsReleaseToRefresh: "Release to Refresh"
    });
```

The above code fetches tasks(). No issues till here.

After this I pasted the same code into another controller say Y.

```
PullToRefresh.init({
        mainElement: ('#page-refresher'),
        onRefresh: function(){
            $scope.history();
        },
        distThreshold : 50, // Minimum distance required to trigger the refresh.
        iconArrow: '<span class="la la-arrow-down"></span>', // The icon for both instructionsPullToRefresh and instructionsReleaseToRefresh
        instructionsPullToRefresh: "Pull Down to Refresh",
        instructionsReleaseToRefresh: "Release to Refresh"
    });
```

Now whenever I try to pull the page of controller X, the pulltorefresh function works and tasks() is fetched. Then if I move to another page's controller Y and pulltorefresh, here instead of history() to execute; the previous tasks() gets executed. I know this is not the way to implement JS functions in AngularJS. Someone kindly guide the right way to implement the pull to refresh module in multiple controllers performing different actions.

Comment: I suspect that you can only call the `init()` function once, and that's why your `onRefresh` function is the original one from X, instead of Y.

Answer (score 1):

PullToRefresh has a [destroy](https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js#api) method that can be used to remove an instance of it.

In each controller you could `init()` PullToRefresh, and then `destroy()` it using the AngularJS `$onDestroy()` lifecycle event. This should prevent an existing instance of PullToRefresh being used in controller Y.

It's a bit hacky, and there may be a better way but give this a try and see if it works.

Controller code:

```
function myController() {
    var self = this;

    var pullToRefreshInstance = PullToRefresh.init({...});

    self.$onDestroy = function() {
        pullToRefreshInstance.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why but `self.$onDestroy` doesn't work at all. I put a log message inside but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Using @nevada_scout 's answer of using destroy() method, I tried solved it myself and luckily it worked.

```
if($rootScope.pullToRefreshInstance != undefined) {
    $rootScope.pullToRefreshInstance.destroy();
    $rootScope.pullToRefreshInstance = undefined;
}

$rootScope.pullToRefreshInstance = PullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: ('#page-refresher'),
    onRefresh: function(){
        //Perform your on refresh action here
    },
    distThreshold : 50,
    setPassiveMode: true,
    iconArrow: '<span class="la la-arrow-down"></span>',
    instructionsPullToRefresh: "Pull Down to Refresh",
    instructionsReleaseToRefresh: "Release to Refresh"
});
```

Assigning the init to a rootscope did the job (Can also use as service).
Then while moving between controllers, the first 3 lines of code will check if there is any previous initiated ptr exist. If it exists then it will destroy it and create a new once specific to the current controller.